# How can I compute the intergral below?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

i is the complex number and (x-y) is a non 0 constant value.
I try to use Euler equation to tackle it. I realize cos is a even function. So, cos(infinity) - cos(-infinity) = 0. But how can I deal with the sin part?

Comment: If you recognize $(x-y)$ is constant than how is this any different from integrating $e^{Ct}$ where $C$ is any constant

Comment: This is a definite integral. Not a indefinite integral.

Comment: Here is the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This isn't a definite integral btw. It is an improper integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $u=it(x-y)$. Then $du=i(x-y)dt$ and your integral becomes 
$$
\int e^{it(x-y)}dt=\frac{-i}{x-y}\int e^udu=\frac{-i}{x-y}(e^{it(x-y)}+c)=
$$

Unfortunately, the bounds on your integral are worrisome (assuming $x-y$ real). Taking $t\to \pm \infty$ is going to wind you around and around the circle in $\mathbb{C}$, yielding a non convergent integral.

You can also conclude by Euler's formula: 
$$
\lim_{t\to \pm \infty}\frac{-i}{x-y}e^{it(x-y)}=
\lim_{t\to \pm \infty}\frac{-i}{x-y}(\cos(t(x-y))+i\sin(t(x-y))
$$
which converges if and only if the real and imaginary part both converge; neither do.

Comment: Be careful, this is a definite integral. The answer should be a number, not a formula.

Comment: yes, isn't there a nice relationship between antiderivatives and definite integrals?

Comment: OMG, I think the answer should be 0. In fact, I want to prove that the integral of the expression above should be a delta function. When y = x, the answer of the integral should be infinity. But how can I prove when y != x, the answer is 0?

Comment: when $y=x$ that integral is $+\infty$. When $y\ne x$ it diverges.

Comment: The answer is definitely not zero. Both cos and sin limits at infinity do not exist. See for yourself by using l'hopitals rule even.